# How to run the blender benchmark on windows?

Tags: installation

I have downloaded the blender benchmark zip file but how do I install / run the benchmark in Windows ? In Mac OS this is all very simple but I really don't know what program I have to start on Windows.

By the way ....after 2,5 years not using Blender I am back again :)

Comment: The new benchmark and website will go live tomorrow (9 Jan). Some additional information about the update can be found [here](https://www.blender.org/press/blender-benchmark-2020-update/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to run the benchmark 1.0 beta 2 on Windows you will have to:

1. Download the .zip archive from https://opendata.blender.org/
2. Extract the .zip
3. Run the `blender-benchmark.exe`

The benchmark website will be updated in January 2020 [according to Ton Roosendaal](https://twitter.com/tonroosendaal/status/1210589234547040263). This will likely include an updated version of the benchmark software as well.

> Note: the benchmark test was with Blender 2.79. The benchmark site
>   gets a complete refresh first half January.

If you're interested in the progress of the new Blender Benchmark, you can check the linked repositories [*Blender Benchmark Bundle*](https://developer.blender.org/source/blender-benchmark-bundle/), [*Blender My Data*](https://developer.blender.org/source/blender-my-data/) and [*Blender Open Data*](https://developer.blender.org/source/blender-open-data/repository/master/) and tickets related to the [*Blender Open Data*](https://developer.blender.org/project/view/82/) project.